# Is there a way to collect fee of transaction?

Tags: rpc, fee, sidecar

I'm looking to collect Extrinsic transfers as images on https://polkadot.subscan.io/

Maybe use api sidecar or rpc to collect this data? Please help me!!!

Thank you so much!!!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In Substrate based chains, like Polkadot, when an extrinsic is included in a block, it emits certain events to notify external entities about changes or conditions in the runtime.

Polkadot-JS API supports a WebSocket subscription on runtime events, for your case, you are interested in [events related to balances](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/substrate/events/#balances). In particular for fees in balance transfers, a `Withdraw` event will tell us the fee amount the sender account paid whereas `Deposit` events will tell us the amount of that fee that was deposited to the Treasury account and the amount that was deposited as tip to the block validator account.

You can have a look to [this section in the Polkadot Integrations guide](https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/build-node-interaction#substrate-api-sidecar) to learn about about how to query blocks with Sidecar and get the events related to fees paid by the extrinsics included in that block.