# Get extrinsic fee using Polkadot.js/api

Tags: polkadot-js, extrinsic, kusama, fee

I want to get extrinsic fee using polkadot.js/api.

I am checking kusama chain.

https://kusama.subscan.io/extrinsic/17981827-3

I need to get `0.00053835621` fee from above extrinsic. Which api can I use in polkadot.js/api?

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure how Subscan is getting this values, but I believe to get the ***Used Fee*** you have to scan the events, see this previous answer in StackExchange: [Is there a way to collect fee of transaction?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/2849/2762)

> In particular for fees in balance transfers, a Withdraw event will
> tell us the fee amount the sender account paid whereas Deposit events
> will tell us the amount of that fee that was deposited to the Treasury
> account and the amount that was deposited as tip to the block
> validator account

The Estimated Fee you can estimated querying the [queryFeeDetails](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/substrate/rpc/#queryfeedetailsextrinsic-bytes-at-blockhash-feedetails) call with the extrinsic encoded.
See this previous answer as an example of how to do it using PolkadotJS: [Estimated fee and Used fee](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/6579/2762)